# Use Ruby on Rails and SSH to access remote MySQL database on remote server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ssh

How do I use SSH to make my RoR db calls to a remote MySQL db on a remote server.  I have the host ip, ssh username, ssh password, db, db username, db password, and port.  Any examples I have seen show the code just in a ruby script but I do not know how to apply that solution to my web application.  Do I need to change anything in my database.yml file?  I appreciate any help...

Answer (score 3):

The way to go about this is to create an SSH Tunnel to the destination database host and point the local server to it.
Check out: [How do I configure Rails for password-less access to remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774264/how-do-i-configure-rails-for-password-less-access-to-remote-database)

Answer (score -7):

You can connect to remote databases from Rails. Simply edit your `database.yml`:

```
development: 
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: password
  host: hostname
  port: port_number
  database: database_name
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question here.