# How do I configure Rails for password-less access to remote database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh

*Note: this is similar to [Use Ruby on Rails and SSH to access remote MySQL database on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923814/use-ruby-on-rails-and-ssh-to-access-remote-mysql-database-on-remote-server), but the OP didn't provide much info, and the only answer given doesn't answer the question.*

#### background

We recently switched our remote database from password authentication to ssh key based authentication.  I have verified that I can access the db through the elegant [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) graphical db client with the following settings (some names intentionally obfuscated):

```
MySQL Host: woofwoof.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
Username:   bowser
Database:   canine
Port:       3306

SSH Host:   salt.woofwoof.com
SSH User:   guardian
SSH Key:    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now I need Rails to connect to the same database, also using ssh key-based authentication.

#### the question

What goes in my `config/database.yml` file?

So far I have:

```
canine:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: canine
    username: bowser
    host: woofwoof.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
    port: 3306
```

... but how do I specify `SSH Host`, `SSH User` and `SSH Key` in the `config/database.yml` file?

#### additional info

Back when our database had password authentication, the following worked:

```
canine:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: canine
    username: bowser
    password: *secret*
    host: woofwoof.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
    port: 3306
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, you need to establish an SSH tunnel the MySQL server.  On the client machine, run:

```
ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 guardian@salt.woofwoof.com
```

That will establish an SSH tunnel to the salt.woofwoof.com server. Any connections to localhost port 3307 will get sent through the tunnel to the remote host on port 3306.

Then just configure your database.yml like you would for a local connection, but specify the forwarded port 3307:

```
canine:
  adapater: mysql2
  database: canine
  username: bowser
  password: *secret*
  port: 3307
```

You may also want to add the ssh tunnel setup to /etc/inittab so that the tunnel is establish after boot.  See http://chxo.com/be2/20040511_5667.html for one example of how to do that.

Comment: Perfect!  I reverse-engineered Sequel Pro and realized it was setting up an SSH tunnel, just as you described.  What's more, your solution works!  :)

Comment: This was really helpful. But you've got a minor error in the answer. You're forwarding through the 3307 port but the latter part of your answer refers to this as the 3007 port. Same for 3306 and 3006.

Comment: This worked for me, with a small correction though. I've used the database's hostname, instead of 127.0.0.1 when setting up the tunnel, like this: ssh -fNg -L 3307:woofwoof.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 guardian@salt.woofwoof.com I've realized I need to user db hostname instead of 127.0.0.1 thanks to this article: https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/205408088-Access-Your-Database-Remotely-Through-an-SSH-Tunnel

Comment: What do the flags do? Specifically -N, which I can see in the help for ssh.

Comment: `-N` is "Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports."

Comment: `-f` tells ssh to run in the background

Comment: `-g` allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports

Comment: @infused for this configuration, what changes would one need to make if multiple databases existed behind `salt.woofwoof.com` and one wanted to avoid connecting to `meowmeow.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com`

Comment: ssh -fNg -L 3307:salt.woofwoof.com:3306 guardian@salt.woofwoof.com

Answer (score 6):

There is also a pure rails solution

add the following to your Gemfile

```
 gem 'net-ssh-gateway'
```

then create a class

```
module RemoteConnectionManager
  SSH_USER = 'YOUR_SSH_USER'

  def self.port_through_tunnel(remote_host, port, local_port: nil, db_host:'localhost')
    return Net::SSH::Gateway.new(remote_host, SSH_USER)
      .open(db_host,port,local_port)
  end
end
```

last change your database.yml

```
  adapter: mysql2
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port:  <%= RemoteConnectionManager.port_through_tunnel('your_ssh_host', 3306, db_host: 'your_db_host_eg_some_aws_rds_db' ) %>
    username: your_db_username
    password: your_db_password
    database: your_db_name
```

if local_port is nil Net/ssh will pick a free one