# How to enable passwordless access to Mysql for Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have this database config which connects to MySQL database using root without the password. How do I configure MySQL so that all database operations coming from my app will work?

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myapp
  pool: 25
  username: root
  password:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  strict: false
```

## possible solution

Answer to this question by chaintng

https://serverfault.com/questions/563714/allow-linux-root-user-mysql-root-access-without-password

```
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
```

along with .my.cnf configuration

```
$ cat ~/.my.cnf 
[client]
user=root
password=''
```

It seems to work, but I am not sure if it is a correct solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26787176/1047207 - Haven't this helped?

Comment: @RAJ No it would not help! I was looking for something that would work with the database configuration intact.

Comment: Root access in Unix means that you are using the system as a root user which has full access rights - you're just connecting to mysql with the (crappy) default mysql username `root`. Very different.